# Custom info window for route plotted through DirectionService

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow

Using the Google Maps API v3, is it possible to customize the layout and content of the infoWindows that are attached to each route marker that's plotted through the DirectionService?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to geocodezip at the Google Maps API Groups for this example on how to achieve this:

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_custom_revgeo.html

There is no out of the box way to do it, you have to essentially place custom markers/infoWindows yourself, and attach dragging listeners to each one of them.